# Java Axis2 IllegalStateException in generated client stub

Tags: java, apache-axis

I'm using Axis2 v1.6.3 to consume https://advertising.criteo.com/API/v201010/AdvertiserService.asmx?WSDL .
Everything works ok for many of the requests, but when trying to call getAccount, an exception is risen in the generated client.

The exception propagated is a `NullPointerException` caused when calling (in the generated stub) `_messageContext.getTransportOut()`.
However, digging further, the problem seems to be due to an `IllegalStateException` thrown by `XMLStreamReader.next` when executing `toOM` for the envelope.

The (slightly modified) stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Jsr173$XMLStreamReaderForString.next(Jsr173.java:1110)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Jsr173$SyncedJsr173.next(Jsr173.java:1138)
    at ----.CriteoStub.toOM(CriteoStub.java:2390)
    at ----.CriteoStub.toOM(CriteoStub.java:2379)
    at ----.CriteoStub.toEnvelope(CriteoStub.java:3657)
    at ----.CriteoStub.getAccount(CriteoStub.java:703)
```

The generated code is:

```
private org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement toOM(final com.criteo.advertising.api.v201010.GetAccountDocument param)
throws org.apache.axis2.AxisFault {

    final javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader xmlReader = param.newXMLStreamReader();
    while (!xmlReader.isStartElement()) {
        try {
            xmlReader.next();     //<---------- here is the exception risen
        } catch (javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException e) {
            throw org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(e);
        }
    }
 //...
```

And, in my case, param content is:

`<xml-fragment/>`

Google shows [related issues in the past](http://java-user.axis.apache.narkive.com/0IFhgj48/axis2-error-while-running-the-axis2-ws-client), but nothing current and no solution.

Any clue on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was caused by the fact that we were using a version for `axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin` different from the axis2 library.

Changing the `axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin` version to 1.6.3 solved the issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I tried to generate client stubs from wsdl with axis 1.7.8 but still have the same error.